# TypeORM one-to-one join in mongodb

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, typescript, typeorm

I am new to TypeORM, so I am sorry in advance if this question sounds silly.

I have 2 tables User and Category. User has a column categoryId which is a foreign key to Category table.

Category table:

```
@Entity()
export class Category {

    @ObjectIdColumn()
    public _id: ObjectID;

    @PrimaryColumn()
    public id: string;

    public toString(): string {
        return `${this.id}`;
    }

}
```

User table

```
@Entity()
export class User {

    @ObjectIdColumn()
    public _id: ObjectID;

    @PrimaryColumn()
    public id: string;

    @Column()
    public categoryId: string;

    @OneToOne(type => Category)
    @JoinColumn()
    category: Category;

    public toString(): string {
        return `${this.id} ${this.categoryId}`;
    }

}
```

I want to fetch category details while querying for user.
The query I am using is:

```
userRepository.findOne({ where, relations: ['category']});
```

Now the problem is when I use @JoinColumn(), it throws me an error.

```
MongoError: bad index key pattern {}: Index keys cannot be empty.
```

When I use @JoinTable(), I donot get expected result.

What are these @JoinColumn() and @JoinTable(). When should I use these ?

Comment: TypeORM was built with the main focus on RDBMS, whereas for MongoDB, being a NoSQL db, it is not a good fit. There are [examples](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/mongodb.md) of how to get it running, however, I also recall having seen blog posts claiming *TypeORM was not built for MongoDB*. For MongoDB you won't need those `@OneToOne` or `@JoinColumn` at all. Unless you are committed to using TypeORM I strongly suggest you take a step back and rethink your design decision and, maybe, opt for another library.

Comment: Waiting for this PR to be merged: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/pull/9494